# Starting sentence with 'however + adjective...'

Tags: grammar

"However valid the arguments for this kind of compensation structure, it introduces more risk for the executive."

For me this sentence should go like this, "However, to valid the argument..."

Can anyone explain this sentence? Is it correct? Can the sentence start with an adjective after *however*?

Comment: I'm not clear on your question. However is not an adjective.

Comment: "However" is an adverb, not an adjective; it's an adverb of degree modifying the adjective "valid". Your sentence is fine. The initial "however" clause is a supplementary adjunct outside clause structure. We understand that to whatever extent the arguments are valid for this kind of compensation, it introduces more risk .....

Comment: Also, "valid" is not a verb, so you can't say "to valid something".  (There is the verb *validate*, though.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have said, the construction is "however valid", introducing a concessive clause, just as other WH-ever words do:

> Whatever they say, ...
>
> Whenever he comes, ...
>
> However they manage it, ...
>
> However valid the arguments are for this kind of compensation structure,

But only in a few cases can the verb 'is/are' be omitted. Often in the case of "however + adjective/adverb":

> However valid the arguments for this kind of compensation structure, ...

and occasionally with other words:

> Whatever the reasons, ...

Answer (score 1):

When you use *however + adjective* it means that it doesn't matter to what extent.

So basically you're saying:

> It doesn't matter to what extent those arguments are valid for this kind of (...)