# why is "be" omitted in the clause of however?

Tags: grammar

> However beautiful the strategy, you should occasionally look at the results.

> No man, however disconcerting his looking, could compromise that.

In the cases above, from what I learned, I think the subject in the clause of "however" should be followed by "be". That is, "however beautiful the strategy **is**" and "however disconcerting his looking **is**". But I don't know why "be" is omitted in such cases.".

Comment: It is a special construction that allows "be" to be omitted. To do so sounds slightly literary. https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/95065/139225

Comment: Do you mean _however disconcerting his look_ or _appearance_? _Looking_ doesn't make sense.